# using Nunit I want to use the Retry Attribute to help my parallel testing in BrowserStack

Tags: c#, appium, nunit, browserstack

I am attempting to add the retry Attribute under the Test Fixture in Nunit but it does not appear to work. Can anyone show me how to add this as a try catch? The error I see is this

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException :
> [BROWSERSTACK_ALL_PARALLELS_IN_USE] All parallel tests are currently
> in use, including the queued tests. Please wait to finish or upgrade
> your plan to add more sessions.

Is there a way for me to add an attribute thta when it sees the error it retries the Test a few minutes later?

Comment: Please post the code that's not working.

Comment: As per [documentation](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/retry.html) the Retry attribute only works on single tests and not on TestFixtures